# gnu parallel mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use GNU parallel to execute several LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE mysql commands where:

- `{1}` is the name of the file which I obtain from a UNIX find command pipe
- `{2}` is the result of a `chop.pl` script that prints out a certain token from the file string according to certain rules

It seems that I am calling GNU parallel the correct way, except it
does not keep the double-quotes around the mysql command after the
`-e`, and it causes it not work.

E.g.

`find /my/folder/ -name "*.txt" | while read i; do chop.pl $i; echo $i; done | parallel -t -N 2 mysql -h localhost -uuser -pxxxxxxx --local-infile=1 -D dbname -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{2}' IGNORE INTO TABLE tblname IGNORE 1 LINES (col1,col2,col3,col4) set col5='{1}', col6='foo'"`

The command it is attempting, lacking the double quotes after `-e`, is like so:

`mysql -h localhost -uuser -pxxxxxxx --local-infile=1 -D dbname -e LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/my/file/name/yadda_yadda-12345678.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE tblname IGNORE 1 LINES (col1,col2,col3,col4) set col5='yadda_yadda', col6='foo'`

Any ideas how to add back the double-quotes after the `-e`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the solution was to escape all double-quotes, single-quotes and parenthesis signs:

`find /my/folder/ -name "*.txt" | while read i; do chop.pl $i; echo $i; done | parallel -t -N 2 mysql -h localhost -uuser -pxxxxxxx --local-infile=1 -D dbname -e \"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'{2}\' IGNORE INTO TABLE tblname IGNORE 1 LINES \(col1,col2,col3,col4\) set col5=\'{1}\', col6=\'foo\'\"`

Answer (score 1):

The lazy and effective way: put the mysql command in a function, then have `parallel` call that, passing `{1}` and `{2}`.

Using functions is actually suggested by the parallel man pages:
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#QUOTING